# Difficulty in Work-Energy theorem and basics of work done by a force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, work

> A time dependent force $F=6t$ acts on a particle of mass 1kg. If the particle starts from rest then what is the work done during the first second?

In my book first they found final velocity and used work energy theorem. My query is after finding final velocity why we can't use $$W = \int fds = \int \frac {6tds \cdot dt} {dt} = 6v\cdot\int_0^1 tdt $$
My answer is 9 but its 4.5

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because $v$ is not a constant with respect to $t$, and so cannot be factored out of the integral.  If you know how $v$ depends on time (and in fact you can do this easily from the kinematic equations) then you can perform the integral
$$
W = \int_0^1 f(t) v(t) \, dt
$$ and you should get the right answer.

Comment: Sir how can we do this by kinematics please explain?